# Finding UTC date corresponding to NewYork midnight

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, jodatime, utc

I have a user who has configured his timezone as `America/New_York` . I have to schedule an event for him which should start in his midnight and end after 24 hours( the next midnight). But I want to store the date in database in `UTC`.

So I wrote following snippet using Joda DateTime.

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(DateTimeZone.forID(user.getTimezone()));
DateTime todayMidnight = dateTime.toDateMidnight().toDateTime();
// now setting the event start and end time
event.setStartTime(todayMidnight.toDate());
event.setEndTime(todayMidnight.plusDays(1).toDate());
```

Note that my server is running in UTC time zone,

`America/New_York` is UTC-5 so I expect startdate to be `4th Feb 2013 5:0:0` but for me it is bringing up start date as `3rd Feb 2013 23:0:0`

Is there anything wrong in above code.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise you to *avoid* using `DateMidnight` entirely. (It's probably okay for New York, but in other time zones there are days where midnight which doesn't exist, due to daylight saving changes.) Use `LocalDate` to represent a date.

For example:

```
DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID(user.getTimezone());
// Defaults to the current time. I'm not a fan of this - I'd pass in the
// relevant instant explicitly...
DateTime nowInZone = new DateTime(zone);
LocalDate today = nowInZone.toLocalDate();
DateTime startOfToday = today.toDateTimeAtStartOfDay(zone);
DateTime startOfTomorrow = today.plusDays(1).toDateTimeAtStartOfDay(zone);

event.setStartTime(startOfToday.toDate());
event.setEndTime(startOfTomorrow.toDate());
```

Comment: Thanks Jon . I will have to read about LocalDate and its usage.Will give above code a try and update here.